# SQL Server Display only lines with all values not equal to 0

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, filtering

In SQL server 2008r2, i want to display only lines where some columns are not equal to '0'

For example: I want to display only lines where columns 2 and 3 are <> '0'

> line 1 : val1 = 2, val2 = 2, val3 = 0
>
> line 2 : val1 = 1, val2 = 0, val3 = 0
>
> line 3 : val1 = 0, val2 = 0, val3 = 5
>
> line 4 : val1 = 10, val2 = 0, val3 = 3
>
> line 5 : val1 = 0, val2 = 0, val3 = 0

In this example, i want to display lines 1,3,4 but not lines 2 and 5 because both columns 2 & 3 are = '0'

I tried with `NOT EXISTS` but it didn't work.

EDIT : 
Hi, i think it's difficult for me to explain clearly what i want, i put you my definitive request, perhaps you could define my need ^^ :

```
select * from CONSULTANT inner join REPORTINGCONSULTANT on CONSULTANT.ID = REPORTINGCONSULTANT.FK_CONSULTANT where [CONSULTANT].[ISDESACTIVE] = '0' and [CONSULTANT].[ISSUPPRIME] = '0' and [CONSULTANT].[INITIALES] not like 'IL%' and [REPORTINGCONSULTANT].[DATEDEBUT] >= '02/06/2014' and [REPORTINGCONSULTANT].[NBCANDIDATSPUSH] <> '0' and [REPORTINGCONSULTANT].[NBCVENVOYESURPOSTE] <> '0' and [REPORTINGCONSULTANT].[NBRDVPROSPECTS] <> '0' and [REPORTINGCONSULTANT].[NBRDVCLIENTS] <> '0' and [REPORTINGCONSULTANT].NBPROSPECTSRENCONTRES] <> '0' and [REPORTINGCONSULTANT].[NBPROSPECTSRENCONTRESBINOME] <> '0' and [REPORTINGCONSULTANT].[NBCLIENTSRENCONTRES] <> '0' and [REPORTINGCONSULTANT].[NBCLIENTSRENCONTRESBINOME] <> '0'
```

When i run only the begining (stop after the date), it counts me 1700 results
If i run the rest, it counts me 0 result

but i can find lines where all lines are true

Comment: Have you tried using a `where` clause?

Comment: I'm not sure your requirement is as simple as you described in the example. If there is more cases you could append to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Count the number of values not equal to 0 by `sign(abs(x))`.

```
SELECT t.* 
FROM dbo.TableName t
WHERE sign(abs(val1))+sign(abs(val2))+sign(abs(val3)) >1
```

It implements the requirement of :

> display only lines where some columns are not equal to '0'

If "some" means val2 and val3, it could be:

```
SELECT t.* 
FROM dbo.TableName t
WHERE sign(abs(val2))+sign(abs(val3)) >0
```

Comment: The sum of abs values is my solution - Thx a lot

Answer (score 1):

> i want to display only lines where columns 2 and 3 are <> '0'

I don't see the particular problem

```
SELECT t.* 
FROM dbo.TableName t
WHERE t.val2 <> 0 AND t.val3 <> 0
```

Comment: if i try that, it wont display me the lines where t.val1 = 0 and t.val <> 0

Comment: You haven't mentioned a column `val`. Apart from that, your requirement was to exclude rows where `t.val2` or `t.val3` are 0. My `Where`-clause does not exclude rows where the first column is0.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are asking to get all rows where val2 <> 0 OR val3 <> 0 based on the result set you are expecting.

```
SELECT TABLE.*  FROM TABLE WHERE val2 <> 0 OR val3 <> 0
```

Comment: I want to have val2 <> 0 and val3 <> 0 in the same way but not exlude when only one val <> 0

Comment: If you want to get results where both <> 0 and where one value <> 0 then you are really needing to use OR. Run this query, it will give you the result set you are asking for.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Tim Schmelter's probably-correct answer, you might also be asking for the `HAVING` clause.

The `WHERE` statement he used is for when the values you're trying to filter are the actual values in a table, or the result of calculations.  That's probably what you're looking for, though your question is so vague it's hard to tell.

However, sometimes people have a hard time filtering out the result of an aggregation that has been performed on the table, such as when you are summing up some values and want to exclude those with a sum equal to that scenario.   So, if you had the following query:

```
SELECT SUM(someValue) AS val1, MAX(someOtherValue) AS val2, AVG(yetAnotherValue) AS val3
FROM someTable
GROUP BY someThing
```

you could filter out places where val2 and val3 are both zero like this:

```
SELECT SUM(someValue) AS val1, MAX(someOtherValue) AS val2, AVG(yetAnotherValue) AS val3
FROM someTable
GROUP BY someThing
HAVING MAX(someOtherValue) != 0 AND AVG(yetAnotherValue) != 0
```